# Count running instances using specific AMI as Cloudwatch metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Is it possible to monitor the number of running EC2 instances of a specific AMI id as a metric that can be placed in a Cloudwatch dashboard?

Similar as

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EC2 --start-time 2019-11-26T10:00:00 --end-time 2019-11-26T23:59
:00 --period 300 --statistics Average --metric-name CPUUtilization --dimensions Name=ImageId,Value=some-id
```

would provide the average CPU utilization of all instances using a specific AMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each EC2 instance metric data is emitted once per minute, so if you take the metric mentioned above and graph SampleCount with a period of 1 minute, you'll get the number of instances.

If you want to add this to a dashboard you should use [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) to avoid confusion if the period changes on the dashboard. If you give the metric an id of `m1`, expression would be

```
m1/(PERIOD(m1)/60)
```